# Unlock a computer bios?

Tags: bios

If someone adds a password to the bios of a computer and make it so that when booting the computer it prompts for the password, is there any way to bypass or overide that protection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take out the CMOS battery, which is on the inside of the computer on the mother board. Wait for 20-30 seconds (less time may be needed, but the exact time varies). This is normally a button battery. Put the battery back, boot, and there should be no more BIOS password.

Comment: Wouldn't work on all laptops though - some Thinkpads (and probably business-grade machines from other manufacturers) keep the password in persistent memory that doesn't need a battery to function.

Comment: @AndréBorie true, but this should get alot of them... either that or you need to re flash it some how. but by that point you might as well just take out the harddrive

Comment: You are right though, usually you couldn't care less about the firmware password unless you need *this* exact machine to boot, such as when you need the TPM to release the drive's encryption key.

Comment: Well thay waa easy thanks dont knoe why i didn't think about that. :)

Comment: @AndréBorie They use non-volatile storage, not persistent memory.

Comment: This is why it's more secure to encrypt your hard drive than to use a bios password.  Or just use both.

Answer (score 3):

Try entering *random strings* in the password field for some couple of times until a **password key** is displayed. Take this key code and:

- Go to https://bios-pw.org/
- Key in the key code that you have in the *input field* and click on **Get password** button
- A list of generated passwords will be displayed depending on the model of your computer.
- So select your matching password and set it to unlock *BIOS*.

**PS**: *Save it somewhere for further usage, otherwise, retry the above steps in case you got to unlock BIOS again.*

Comment: this is also covered by another answer

Comment: For the coverage, there is no clear coverage of my answer, neither with clear steps, nor with a the link for a password generation. That's why i saw it useful that i add a clearer answer

Comment: The other answer refers to an app. You could post your link as a comment to the other answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm still not convinced that adding it as a comment would be more useful than creating a full clearer answer. Anyways i wait, and if i see it having a bad impact, then i will delete it right away. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't have the same content as another answer. You can offer an edit to the other answer to add your link

Answer (score 2):

If you know the brand of the motherboard, you can find the right software to reset it. I had used it long time ago. However, you may need to boot it from A: drive if there is any :-) , otherwise you may use a CD drive.  Another way is to short the clear CMOS jumper on the motherboard itself if one is present.

Besides, If you enter the wrong password a few times on a laptop,  it will be locked with a message something like a “System Disabled” or “Password check failed. System Halted” message with some numbers under the message. Power off and on the computer  try again and do not forget to write the numbers down. Then, get BIOS Master Password Generator and use the number you noted before and try the passwords created for you. Depending your laptop model press Enter or Ctrl+Enter after entering the code. good luck